# Jquery grow effect like spray

Tags: jquery, spray

Hi I was wondering if there was a jquery grow function that was the same as sample 2/demo 2 on the spray page here.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/effects/grow_sample.html

Dont want to use spray as I have most of my site effects with jquery.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `scale` effect in jQueryUI can be used to achieve this.

[More information](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! , Just saw it the samples I saw was growing from the right to left but have the correct page now to do this just need to add jquery-ui.min.js to my header.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `.animate()` method for this.

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/FWwUv/).

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

$('div.inner').animate({
    'margin':'100px'
}, 1000);​
```

**Steps** for full effect

1. Increase the margins when there is no content.
2. Then when the animation completes, remove the margin
3. set the actual final width and
4. then append the content you want to display.